# Solving $\frac{3}{2} e^y y^2 + y = 0$

Tags: calculus

Trying to solve the following Eq, but none of the usual methods seem to work:

$$3/2 \exp{(y)}y^2+y=0$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, y is just a real variable

Comment: Equations with the unknown both inside and outside of a transcendental function usually have no closed-form solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice review of classical tools from calculus.

You can write this as
$$ y(1 + 1.5 y e^y) = 0.$$
This is zero when either of the two terms $y$ or $(1 + 1.5 y e^y)$ are zero. Clearly there is a zero at $y = 0$, and that handles the first term.
Now we consider the second term:
$$ 1 + 1.5 y e^y.$$
As a function, $f(y) = 1 + 1.5 y e^y$ has derivative $f'(y) = 1.5 e^y + 1.5 y e^y = 1.5 e^y(1 + y)$. Thus $f'(y) = 0$ exactly when $y = -1$. Since $f'(y) > 0$ for $y > -1$ and $f'(y) < 0$ for $y < -1$, $f(y)$ has its only minimum at $y = -1$.

What is the value at $y = -1$? It's $1 - 1.5 e^{-1} > 0$. So $f(y)$ is never zero.

And so $y(1 + 1.5y e^y) = y f(y) = 0$ has only one solution: $y = 0$. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: Very neat way of solving it, thanks!

Comment: Could you please add a tad more explanation as to how you concluded f(y) is never zero based on its derviative behaviour around -1 :(

Comment: @user929304 I found the minimum of $f(y)$. The minimum is greater than $0$. If the smallest value that $f(y)$ ever takes is bigger than zero, then $f(y)$ is never zero.

Comment: But f'(y)>0 for y>-1 and f'(y)<0 for y<-1, doesn't that make y = -1 an inflexion point for f?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of your comment is. But no. As $f'$ changes from negative to positive, it is clear that $f'$ is increasing. So $f$ has positive second derivative at -1.

Answer (score 1):

If $ay^2e^y+y=0$,
then
$ye^y=-1/a$.

By the definition of the
Lambert W function
(see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function,
for example)
$y=W^{-1}(-1/a)$.